# How to change CSS attributes with a button in AngularJS?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, background-image

With a click of a button I want to be able to change the background image of my site. How can I change the background image attribute on my body in CSS using AngularJS?

CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: #00471c;
  background-image: url(http://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/brushed-alum.png);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="newBackground" placeholder="Image URL for new background...">

<button ng-click="ng-style=body{background-image: url({{newBackground}})}" placeholder="Change background...">Change background</button>
```

I actually have it where the button executes a function what gets an image URL that is related to the inputted text, but for the sake of this question this is how I have set it up.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8bc4bau6/)

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, and I am not certain I do, you can easily change the CSS style associated with a tag using the ng-style ([ngStyle](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle)) directive.  The  tag would have to be inside of the tag that has the ng-app directive, so you are pretty much forced to put ng-app on the HTML tag.

You would then control the background image with the ng-style directive:

```
<body ng-style="myChosenStyle">
```

Which would be controlled in a controller somewhere like:

```
$scope.myChosenStyle = 'background-image: url(' + $scope.myImageUrl + ')';
```

You'd have to look for a form button press or something to actually control when the $scope.myChoseStyle var was set, but that's not hard.

Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

It's usually recommended that you handle all DOM changes in directives, so that's why I've chosen the approach below. ([John Papa Style Guide on GitHub - Manipulate DOM in a Directive](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#manipulate-dom-in-a-directive))

Try this ([jsbin](http://jsbin.com/gomogixoto/1/edit?html,js,output)):

JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', []);

angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('MyController',MyController);

MyController.$inject = ['$scope'];

function MyController($scope) {
  $scope.newBackground = '';
  // all your other code
}

angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('backgroundChanger',backgroundChanger);

function backgroundChanger() {
  var d = {
    link: link
  };

  function link(scope, el, attrs) {
    el.on('click',function() {
      var bg = attrs.backgroundChanger;

      $('body').css({
        'background-image': 'url('+bg+')'
      });
    });
  }

  return d;  
}
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
      <input type="text" ng-model="newBackground" placeholder="Image URL for new background..." />

      <button background-changer="{{newBackground}}" placeholder="Change background...">Change background</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

This approach has a couple benefits:

1. You can re-use the directive (you can theoretically make any element then a "background changer")
2. You separate the concerns (models and information stay in the controller, while style changes are handled in the directive